# Using string instead of object in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using Redux for the session management in a universal React APP. In the store I'm storing a JWT token (a string) containing the basic information of the user. I know that usually Redux takes objects or arrays (which are objects as well), but… is it valid to use a string instead of an object? For example, like in:

```
store = {
    Articles: [
        {
            title: 'title1', 
            text: 'Lorem ipsum'
        },
        {
            title: 'title 2', 
            text: 'Lorem ipsum'
        },
    ],
    Session: 'mytoken'
}
```

Or maube I should do something like this?

```
store = {
    Articles: [
        {
            title: 'title1', 
            text: 'Lorem ipsum'
        },
        {
            title: 'title 2', 
            text: 'Lorem ipsum'
        },
    ]

    Session: {
        token: 'mytoken'
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: The second  option seems reasonable to me, though I guess the question is why you would want to store the JWT in state does not really make a lot of sense to me

Comment: Is an universal app. I want to manage the state of the whole app with Redux, so I have the JWT in two places: the store, and a cookie that is created/removed by Redux action. In front login process JWT is returned from fetch request, and then the Redux action `logIn()` is triggered and cookie with JWT is created. When we navigate in the app we have token in store. When we reload, backend React rendering reads the cookie and add the token to backend store, passing it along all data to view, which add it to `window.data`. Frontend rendering takes `window.data` and create frontend store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either of the options you mentioned, just make sure you have your reducer setup appropriately for either case.
If the only information related to `Session` that is relevant to you is just the JWT, you can store it as a string. If you need to store other information along with the token, the second implementation is preferable since you never know you might need it in the future. I would prefer the second option in that case.